# include multiple classes in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="bjqs video">
```

What is the right way of being able to include and select both classes from the html into the jquery below as at moment it is only including one class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#banner-video_<?php echo $key; ?>').bjqs({
    animtype:'slide'
  });  
});
```

Comment: What is the value of ```$key```?

Comment: @JonJaques $key is in a for each loop, it is the value for each question number

Comment: Ahh, wondering if it made a difference in the answer but looks like not. Also, it will work fine regardless - but my ocd says you should make sure the whole document.ready wrapper is outside of the loop. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors:

```
$('.bjqs.video')
```

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Use commas between the selectors as one string if you want to use multiple selectors, and it will work.

Example:

```
$(".classone , .classtwo").method();
```

Note that this will match all elements that match either the first selector or the second selector (or both); it doesn't force matched elements to match both. If you want to force matching element having BOTH classes, do this instead:

Example:

```
$(".classone.classtwo").method();
```

Comment: You should note though, this will match all elements that match *either* the first selector *or* the second selector (*or both*); it doesn't force matched elements to match *both*, which is likely the desired behavior based on that HTML fragment

Comment: @nbrooks Oh then in that case just specify both like in css with no comma in between. Question is not very clear IMO

Comment: I know, that's why I was just saying you should clarify and make it explicit here. Good answer all the same

Comment: @nbrooks thx thats a good idea I added the clarification in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the it as follows to target the specific ul and the class assigned to it.

```
$('ul.bjqs.video');
```